# Select2 not loading data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-select2

I recently upgraded to Rails 5.2 and ruby 2.5.1 and my select box stopped working.

I had to change requiere file in my `admin.js`and add the full version to even view the select box

```
//= require select2-full
```

but now the ajax query to get the data or even the initial selection is not displaying any results. I am using [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to pass data to my js and I have checked that gon has the correct values. My js.coffee is as follows:

```
clientFormatResult = (client) ->
  client.email

clientFormatSelection = (client) ->
  client.email

$ ->
  $select_input = $('#publish_to')
  $select_input.val(' ')
  $select_input.select2({
    width: '420px'
    height: 'auto'
    placeholder: "Search"
    minimumInputLength: 2
    multiple:true
    closeOnSelect: true
    tokenSeparators:[',',' ']
    ajax: {
      url: $select_input.data('search-endpoint')
      data: (term, page) ->
        {
          q: term # search term
          page_limit: 10
        }
      results: (data, page) -> # parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
        console.log("result")
      # since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
        results: data.manage_clients
      }
    initSelection: (element, callback) ->
      callback(gon.published_to)
    formatResult: clientFormatResult
    formatSelection: clientFormatSelection
  })
```

My controller search endpoint:

```
def search
    clients = Client.where("email like '%#{params[:q]}%'").map { |c| { :id => c.id, :email => c.email } }
    render :json => clients
  end

private
  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :organisation, :assigned_team)
  end
```

search-endpoint result:

```
{
"manage_clients": [
{
"id": 46,
"email": "aaaa@example.net"
},
{
"id": 365,
"email": "bbbb@example.org"
}
]
}
```

Extract of the view source code where the select input is:

```
<div class="input string required publish_to">
<label class="string required control-label" for="report_clients">
Publish to
</label>
<input data-search-endpoint="/my-endpoint-search" id="publish_to" name="publish_to" type="hidden" value="" multiple="" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true"><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 420px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><ul class="select2-selection__rendered"><li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Search for a client" style="width: 418px;"></li></ul></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
<div>
<a class="add_button button" href="/some_url">Action</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried the solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626982/it-does-not-work-select2-ruby-on-rails-5) of chenging the controller respond_to
but no change.
I also tried adding a `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax call as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636385/select2-not-loading-remote-data)
Adding `.select2('val',[])` at the end of the first select2
I tried manually adding `{ id: '1', text:'example' }` to the `initSelection`
I am not getting any error in the console

But the ajax call doesn't seem to be working. In the console there are no calls to the search-endpoint.

Comment: @debugger I have a client_params defined in another action, can that affect the search action?

Comment: @dbugger I have added the code

Comment: @dbugger if I manually call the search action it works just fine, with or without params

Comment: @dbugger from the logs, select2 is not running the ajax call nor the initSelection

Comment: @marimaf could you share the full code of a generated page where your select2 is on?

Comment: @draganstankovic I have added  an extract where the select2 input is, as the entire page code is huge. Let me know if that helps. Thank!

Comment: @marimaf Could you provide live website link of that you are working on.

Comment: @NirajKaushal Sorry, I can't. What would you like to see?

Comment: @marimaf I just wanted to make sure that all js is loading in frontend or not. I am not fully sure but I think there is problem in frontend(As you stated `But the ajax call doesn't seem to be working.`).

Comment: @marimaf Can you confirm in your browser dev tools that there are no console errors and that in the network tab you get all the resources loaded (status 200)?

Comment: @draganstankovic no console errors

Comment: @NirajKaushal from the sources tab I can see that select2 css and js is being loaded

Comment: @marimaf read this article https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35#no-more-hidden-input-tags btw which version of select2 you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using select2 4.0 and the code was designed for 3.5

I had to change my input to a select, and add there a multiple="multiple" attribute instead of declaring it as part of the select2 options. That was the main change to make it work. After that a few tweaks I had to change the initSelection formatter and change the ajax results from results to processResults. The final code is this:

```
%select#publish_to{ :name => 'publish_to', :multiple => 'multiple', :type => 'hidden', "data-lookup-endpoint" => my_endpoint_path }
```

And the coffeescript:

```
formatValues = (values) ->
  data = []
  i = 0
  while i < values.length
    data.push
      id: values[i].id
      text: values[i].email
    i++
  data

$ ->
  $select_input = $('#publish_to')
  $select_input.val('')
  $select_input.select2({
    placeholder: 'Search for a Client'
    width: '420px'
    height: 'auto'
    data: formatValues(gon.published_to)
    allowClear: true
    minimumInputLength: 2
    tokenSeparators:[',',' ']
    ajax: {
      url: $select_input.data('lookup-endpoint')
      dataType: 'json'
      data: (term, page) ->
        {
          q: term # search term
        }
      processResults: (data, page) -> # parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
      # since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
        results: formatValues(data.manage_clients)
      }
  })
  # To set initial values:
  $('#publish_to').val(getIds(gon.published_to)).trigger 'change'
```

controller, changed the param from `[:q]` to `[:q][:term]`:

```
def search
    clients = Client.where("email like '%#{params[:q][:term]}%'").map { |c| { :id => c.id, :email => c.email } }
    render :json => clients
  end
```